# Refine by, returning results back to template

Tags: search, module, mysql

In a new site I am working on, I have a refine section that allows users to select from a range of checkbox questions (around 40 checkboxes, 7 questions). I have currently wrapped these in a form, which actions to a custom Expression Engine module. Here I want to complete the 'search' of which entries match the full 'refine by' the user has submitted.

My question is, how can I return the entries that are output by my 'refine by' criteria in the module. Somehow, I need to return back to the template the list of entry id's? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you could build this yourself the way you have been, it would be much quicker to use one of the ready-made add-ons that already do this.

Reefine is good for your use case: http://www.ralphmedia.co.uk/docs/reefine/

And also Low Search can handle that too: http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search

If you really do want to continue building the functionality from scratch, many EE devs like to hijack the native channel class for this - so first add your custom logic to fetch all the relevant `entry_id`s and then pipe them through to the native channel entries method (typically via the `fixed_order` or `entry_id` parameters).

Here's a rundown of how that technique works: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:sYbC0xhLkDIJ:https://dmlogic.com/blog/extending-the-expression-engine-channel-module+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

... still though, not much point re-inventing the wheel if you don't need to.